# Send selected option value by parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, frontend

I am developing a java application in which I get the data from the database and present it in a   but I do not know how to get the selected value and send per parameter.

JSP

```
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${!empty param.descricao}">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro">  


     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">

         <h3>${registro.descricao}</h3>
         <p>${registro.codigo}</p>
         <div class="linha_compra"></div><br/><br/>


          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <p>${registro.valor}</p>  

    <select id="parcelas">
    <option value="1"> ${registro.prod_parc1}</option>
   <option value="2">${registro.prod_parc2}</option>
 <option value="3">${registro.prod_parc3}</option>
 <option value="4"${registro.prod_parc4}</option>
<option value="5"${registro.prod_parc5}</option>
<option value="6"${registro.prod_parc6}</option>
<option value="7"${registro.prod_parc7}</option>
<option value="8"${registro.prod_parc8}</option>
<option value="9"${registro.prod_parc9}</option>
<option value="10"${registro.prod_parc10}</option>
</select>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
 <button type="button" onclick="" class="botao_comprar"><a href="http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/Carrinho?descricao=${registro.descricao}&valor=${registro.valor}&parcela=">COMPRAR</a></button> 
          </div>

    </div>
 </c:foreach>
```

Comment: Have you heard about [HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and [request parameters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm)?